# NixOS Postgresql authentication not being updated

Tags: postgresql, nixos

I have the following snippet in my configuration.nix:

```
services.postgresql = {
    enable = true;
    authentication = lib.mkForce ''
      # GENERATED
      host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
      host all all ::/0 md5
    '';
  };
```

After a rebuild switch and service restart, the pg_hba.conf remains the same as before changing that `authentication` value.

What have I messed up/missed?